# insert timestamp values in 3 minute steps

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert timestamp values of 3 minute steps (given a start and end date) into a table with just one timestamp column.

I currently switch from sql server to mysql. I would know how to do it for the former database in SQL but am not sure about the latter. Thanks.

This is my current (not working) miserable attempt:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
begin
    declare StartTS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT null;
    declare EndTS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT null;

    set StartTS = '2012-01-01 00:00:00';
    set EndTS = '2014-01-01 00:00:00';

    start transaction;
      while StartTS < EndTS do
        insert into timestamps (TimeStampEntry) values (StartTS);
        SET StartTS  = StartTS  + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
      end while;
      commit;
end
//

DELIMITER ;

call test();
```

PS:

```
create table TimeStamps (
        Id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       TimeStampEntry DATETIME,
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

current sproc:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myProc`(IN t1 timestamp, IN t2 timestamp)
BEGIN

  WHILE t1 <= t2 DO
INSERT INTO timestamps (TimeStampEntry) Values (t1)  ;
    SET t1 = DATE_ADD(t1, INTERVAL 180 SECOND);
    #SET t1 = t1 + INTERVAL 180 SECOND;
  END WHILE;
END
```

call:

```
CALL myProc('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(IN t1 timestamp, IN t2 timestamp)
BEGIN

  WHILE t1 <= t2 DO
INSERT INTO test (ts) Values (t1)  ;
    SET t1 = DATE_ADD(t1, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);
  END WHILE;
END;


CALL myProc(now(), ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5672e/9

Or change your line:

```
SET StartTS  = StartTS  + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
```

to

```
SET StartTS  = ADDDATE(StartTS, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);
```

Comment: It works-ish. However, I seem to get the odd error: Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2010-03-28 01:00:00'  any ideas?

Comment: can you reproduce at sqlfiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: It's probably related to an issue with daylight saving... So try to set the timezone to UTC or try something like this: SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00'

Comment: I am just having a look at sql fiddle. Not sure whether I can create sprocs there. I will put some code as PS. BTW the datetime should b UTC maybe I can ensure this in the loop. I understand that the data is stored as UTC anyway.

Comment: show the output of this: SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE '%time_zone%'

Comment: 'system_time_zone', 'GMT Daylight Time'
'time_zone', 'SYSTEM'

Comment: Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: SET time_zone = timezone;
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html