# speed up insert of sproc

Tags: mysql

This question is related to:

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801680/insert-timestamp-values-in-3-minute-steps)

It uses this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(IN t1 timestamp, IN t2 timestamp)
BEGIN

  WHILE t1 <= t2 DO
INSERT INTO test (ts) Values (t1)  ;
    SET t1 = DATE_ADD(t1, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);
  END WHILE;
END;
```

invoke like this:

```
CALL myProc(now(), ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE));
```

which is extremely slow. Is there any way to speed this up (e.g. do things differently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wrapping this in a transaction would improve things.... something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(IN t1 timestamp, IN t2 timestamp)
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;

   WHILE t1 <= t2 DO
      INSERT INTO test (ts) Values (t1)  ;
      SET t1 = DATE_ADD(t1, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);
   END WHILE;

COMMIT;

END
```

I just threw that together and haven't tested it but I think that might help.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why I get this: Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine myProc 1305. Does it go on the stack because it is in one transaction?

Comment: I believe you need to set that max_sp_recursion_depth variable.  I think that by default it is 0.  You can do something like `set max_sp_recursion_depth = 100`.

Comment: mmh even then I get Error Code: 1436. Thread stack overrun. why does the above code need recursion/ a stack?

Comment: So I updated my own example... I misunderstood your block of code.  It needs recursion if A calls A inside A, right?  I misread that last line as being part of your proc, which I guess actually isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can speed-up your procedure by using temporary table.
Here's the plan:

- create tmp table
- fill tmp table with data you want to insert
- do **one** INSERT query that requires disk writing/index rebuilding

Somethin like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(IN t1 timestamp, IN t2 timestamp)
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (ts timestamp);
  WHILE t1 <= t2 DO
    INSERT INTO tmp SET ts = t1;
    SET t1 = DATE_ADD(t1, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE);
  END WHILE;
  INSERT INTO test (ts) SELECT ts FROM tmp;
  DROP TABLE tmp;
END;
```